# Fatal Error MapKit Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, mapkit

Hi i was trying to add a MapKit to my iOS apk with the center and zoom of a town near my city i was following a tutorial but in my case i got an error i add the error message and the code. I'm using Xcode 7 and Swift 2 [image]

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        maptal()

    }

    func maptal()
    {
        let tallat:CLLocationDegrees = 27.175015
        let tallon:CLLocationDegrees = 78.042139

        let tajcordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: tallat, longitude: tallon )

        let latdelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let longdelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

        let tajspan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: latdelta, longitudeDelta: longdelta)

        let tajregion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: tajcordinate, span: tajspan)

        mapView.setRegion(tajregion, animated: true)

        let tajanotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        tajanotation.title = "taj mahal"
        tajanotation.subtitle = "holita"
        tajanotation.coordinate = tajcordinate

        mapView.addAnnotation(tajanotation)

    }

}
```

Comment: Verify that your `mapView` IBOutlet is properly connected.